# Regex to match 2 letters separately

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a word list :

```
Sup
Past
P.S. Away
Test
Set
Lapse
Space
```

Now, When I type ps, I need to match all words containing one occurrence of "p" and "s" in the word.
So output would be :

```
Sup
Past
P.S. Away
Lapse
Space
```

Regexes Tried :

```
/ps/ // checks for ps as a combination 
/p{1}.s{1}/ // Selects the needful but not sup or space  (s preceding p)
```

Comment: Could you please post the code you have written yourself in an attempt to solve this. SO is to help you solve problems with code you've written, it is not a code writing service.

Comment: Rory - was editing to add the tried solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this using postive look aheads

```
/^(?=.*p)(?=.*s).*$/mi
```

[**Regex Example**](http://regex101.com/r/jO0qU9/1)

- `^` anchors the regex at the start of the string
- `(?=.*p)` postive look ahead. checks if the string contains `p`
- `(?=.*s)` postive look ahead. checks if the string contains `s`
- `.*` matches anything
- `$` anchors the regex at the end of the string

Comment: Thanks a lot nu11p01n73R. Had been struggling for more than an hour. Will be exploring these types of regex patterns to learn more about these

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?=.*p)(?=.*s)[a-z .]+$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/33

```
var re = /^(?=.*p)(?=.*s)[a-z .]+$/gmi;
var str = 'Sup\nPast\nP.S. Away\nTest\nSet\nLapse\nSpace';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method using regex logical OR operator `|`.

```
/^(?:.*p.*s.*|.*s.*p.*)$/mi
```

OR

```
/^.*(?:p.*s|s.*p).*$/mi
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jO0qU9/2)

Comment: Thanks Avinash but the input letters(ps) size may vary with the user input. So forming all permutations might be a bit cumbersome. Look ahead seems to be the solution for me

Answer (score 0):

Try below regex:

```
(((s{1}|S{1})(\w*|\W*)(p{1}|P{1}))|((p{1}|P{1})(\w*|\W*)(s{1}|S{1})))
```

http://regex101.com/r/mX3mG1/1